# Codeigniter where clause with array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

in Codeigniter This is my Controller => wishlist function

```
  $data = array(
  'user_id' => $this->_user_id
  );
  $order_by = "id";
  $query = $this->Database_model->get_data('wishlist','*', $data, $order_by);

  print_r($query);
```

RESULT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [item_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 2
            [tarix] => 2018-03-13 00:00:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [item_id] => 15
            [user_id] => 2
            [tarix] => 2018-03-13 00:00:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [item_id] => 10
            [user_id] => 2
            [tarix] => 2018-03-13 00:00:00
        )

)
```

And now I want to get all "**items**" table datas WHERE id = **all these "item_id"** inside array.

I tried to create new array and push all item_id inside it, using foreach, but in Codeigniter I can't give it to query.

Comment: Are you saying you want a `where in` statement?

Comment: You could use the query that built this as a subquery of your next query. `where id in(select id ...)`

Comment: @Kisaragi yes where x=y or z=u and etc like this

Comment: @chris85 how can I use it in this situation?

Comment: To pass an array for `where in` your query needs to use `$this-db->where_in('column', $array);`  Please edit your question to include `get_data()`

Comment: I don't know `Codeigniter` but you can use a subquery in mysql easily enough which should give you what you want. Roughly `select * from items where id in (select item_id from wishlist where ...)`

Comment: @chris85 I will try this also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:
In your controller

```
$data = array(
    'user_id' => $this->_user_id
);
$order_by = "id";
$query = $this->Database_model->get_data('wishlist','*', $data, $order_by);

$where = array();
foreach ($query as $key => $value)
    array_push($where, $value->item_id); //  Must be item_id

$my_items = $this->Database_model->get_custom_items('items', $where);
```

In your model

```
public function get_custom_items($table, $where)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where_in('id', $where); // Must be id
    return $this->db->get($table)
}
```

Comment: Worked bro, but there is 2 little mistake in your code: in 9. line: id must be item_id, and in model item_id must be id. Thanks.

Comment: `$this->db->select('*');` is not necessary to write -- it is implied.  `return $this->db->where_in('id', $where)->get($table);`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the where_in passes the second parameter not in array format.

In Model :
$this->db->where_in('id', array($where));